# Find and Replace for same characters in both variables in single shot

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find and replace in more than one scalar variables which stored content (content will vary for each string) Hence I need to insert two lines for same replacement for both variables.

```
$str1=~s/\_/&underscore\;/g;
$str1=~s/\^/&carrot\;/g;

$str2=~s/\_/&underscore\;/g;
$str2=~s/\^/&carrot\;/g;
```

Is there any possibilities to replace in a single shot/simultaneously for all string to replace. Note that content will vary in strings. (May be my way of asking question is kid but I am doing the replacement more than 200 lines however trying to reduce the coding lines)

Comment: Why not using a sub?

Comment: @Toto: Can we reduce the line's for replacement if I am using sub? If yes please I am requesting the way in detail to solve.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/lib/HTML/Entities.pm

Comment: @mwp: Its not entities replacement. Its a content find and replace process.

Comment: Well, okay. The example you've given us definitely *is* entities replacement, so I thought it was worth a mention. :)

Comment: @mwp: No worries. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put your variables in a `for` loop, which will alias `$_` to each of them in turn. Note that neither underscore nor semicolon need to be escaped inside a regex pattern

```
for ( $str1, $str2 ) {
    s/_/&underscore;/g;
    s/\^/&carrot;/g;
}
```

However both of those are non-standard entities. Have you declared them yourself? And you probably mean `caret` rather than `carrot`, which is a vegetable! I have seen it called `&Hat;`, but I think that is also non-standard. You could always use `&#x5E;` (and `&#x5F;` for the underscore)

Comment: Excellent answer. (I will change the entity name also)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do it would be to define your mapping rules, build a regex from those rules, and a provide function to apply them. Here's a stab at it:

```
my %map = (
  "_" => "&underscore;",
  "^" => "&caret;",
);

sub apply_map {
  $_[0] =~ s/(${\
    join "|", map quotemeta, keys %map
  })/$map{$1}/g;
}

apply_map $str1;
apply_map $str2;
```

And, borrowing Borodin's answer to apply the map to multiple strings in fewer statements:

```
foreach ($str1, $str1) {
  apply_map $_;
}
```

Or, modify apply_map to take multiple arguments:

```
sub apply_map {
  s/(${\
    join "|", map quotemeta, keys %map
  })/$map{$1}/g foreach @_;
}

apply_map $str1, $str2;
```

Note the `quotemeta`. This prevents any special characters in the map keys from affecting the behavior of the regexp. I'm also using `${\ .. }` syntax to interpolate an expression in the `s///`, but it might be clearer to build a separate pattern string. If all the things you're replacing are one character long, you can join with `''` and use a character class (e.g. `[_^]`) instead of joining with `|`.